# How to fix 'C2061 syntax error identifier 'stack'' in visual studio?

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm using stack in my code and it shows this error. Other questions say I have circular dependency but I only have 1 header file

```
//function.h
#pragma once 

void dfs(int start, int goal, bool visited[], int **matrix, int size,
         bool &found, stack<int>& path);
```

```
//function.cpp
#include "function.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void dfs(int start, int goal, bool visited[], int **matrix, int size,
         bool &found, stack<int>& path)
{
    visited[start] = true;
    cout<<start<<" ";
    path.push(start);

    if (start == goal)
        found = true;

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        if (visited[k] == false && matrix[start][k] && found == false )
            dfs(k,goal,visited,matrix,size,found,path);
        path.pop();
    }
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include "function.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    stack<int> path;

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        visit[i] = false; //init visit

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new int[N]; // build rows

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            fin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    dfs(start, end, visit, matrix, 5, found, path);    
}
```

It should run but it keeps giving me this syntax error: "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'stack' "

Comment: In your function.h you need to `#include <stack>` before you can use it

Comment: You should start by indenting your coder properly. This makes (at least me) people more likely to want to read the code and help you.

Comment: @RedX sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and coding. Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 2):

Your header file should look like this

```
//function.h
#pragma once 

#include <stack>

void dfs (int start, int goal, bool visited[], int **matrix, int size, bool 
&found, std::stack<int>& path);
```

You need to `#include <stack>` before the `dfs` function prototype is seen.

You should fully qualify the type name `stack` (i.e. `std::stack` not `stack`) because `using namespace std;` is a [very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) in a header file.